# Centralized rollback-for using @transactional

Tags: spring, rollback, transactional

Is it possible to tell Spring to rollback for exception `MyException` as well as `RuntimeException` in the XML configuration while using `@transactional`?

I know it is possible to set the rollback for in the annotation but it seems redundant if I have lots of services that would all set the same exceptions.

I saw peoples suggesting to create a custom transactional annotation but I'd prefer not to use a custom annotation and stick with a Spring one.

I know that its possible to use advices but never saw examples where you can use the annotation at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply achieve this by using spring transaction advice tags:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
      <tx:attributes>
      <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="MyException" no-rollback-for="OtherException"/>
      </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
```

check Spring doc transaction management section for more details:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html